# sonar doesn't scan *.java file

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a java web project containing 4 files.

1. demo.java
2. web.xml
3. index.jsp
4. pom.xml

Execute command

> clean verify sonar:sonar

Sonar only checked the `web.xml`, `index.jsp`, `pom.xml`. It did not check `demo.java`.  Sonar version:6.5

[image]

Comment: what did you assign to sonar.sources? show us the properties you have assigned for it

Comment: what sonar version is that? is your sonar project referencing java files too?

Comment: @RajuSharma i use maven plugin

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ sonar version6.5 , installed java plugin.look https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAnDn.png

Comment: 'demo' may be a reserved keyword on sonar, so it will not scan this file. try to change the name.

Comment: @KemalDuran No effect

Comment: @senz : logs of the analysis should help you understand what's going on. Pass '-X' switch to analysis, review Scanner logs and update your post with findings.

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam  very thks ,The log shows that I did not set the source file, doesn't  compile java file

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam  The problem has been settled

Answer (score 2):

FindBugs static analysis class file not java file.

If you want use findbugs rules you should:

1. compile java file to class file.
2. config sonar-project.properties add sonar.java.binaries

   `sonar.sources=.
   sonar.java.binaries=target/classes`

BTW. I suggest launch analysis from Maven or Gradle.

[Analyzing+Source+Code](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code)

OR

You can use default sonarway.

---

[image: show static analysis tools]

Answer (score 0):

setting compile Folder，The problem has been settled